# I am having trouble retrieving information stored in an associative array.

Tags: arrays, associative

I am very new to programming, and am in a programming class.  I have having trouble retrieving stored information in my associative array.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Lifespans</title>
<link rel ="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sample.css" />
</head>

<body>
<h1>Lifespans</h1>
<?php
$animal = $_POST['animal'];

$lifespans = array('Mouse' => "4", => 'Queen Bee' => "5", 'Squirrel' => "20", 'Rattlesnake' => "22", => 'Pheasant' => "27", => 'Mallard Duck' => "29", => 'Bear' => "40", => 'Box Turtle' => "123");

$lifespan=$lifespans[$animal];

print("<p>The $animal has an average lifespan of $lifespan years.</p>");


?>
<a href="lifespans.html"> Try another animal..</a>
</body>
</html>
```

thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: What is the value of `$animal` when you receive it from your POST method? Have you checked to make sure it's a valid key value in your associative array?

Comment: You have many extra  =>  tokens in the array(). `, =>` is meaningless and should be an error.

Comment: thanks! i was receiving an error about => but not sure how to go about putting those values in the array without those.

Comment: the value of $animal is whatever the user inputs from the html page.

Comment: thanks Phil Perry! you were right, i was including extra => in between seperate keys and values.  problem solved!